# Jquery page load even with css effect on html website

Tags: jquery, html, css, notifications

I created a top show notification which is automatically hide after 5 sec. The issue I am facing is , due to much more stylesheet and js file in my webpage the page loading time is increase in between this time my notification show and hide but I didn't see it properly becouse of my webpage late loading.

**What I can do?**

It is possible to solve when we add jquery , where if page fully loaded then after this notification show otherwise not. But I am not familiar of jquery or JavaScript , ask for helping anyone wanna here who help me t create jquery or solve this issue .

My code is given below.

```css
#myTostwarning {        
        position: absolute;
        top:0;left:0;        
        border-radius:0;
        font-size:14px;
        margin:0;
        width:100%;
        z-index:1000;
        overflow: hidden;
        background:#fff5b3;        
        line-height: 16px;
        padding:18px 36px; 
        -webkit-box-shadow:2px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
        box-shadow:2px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
        cursor:default;color:#333;
        }
       #myTostwarning a{
       color: #333;
       }  
#myTosterror {      
        position: absolute;
        top:0;left:0;        
        border-radius:0;
        font-size:14px;
        margin:0;
        width:100%;
        z-index:1000;
        overflow: hidden;
        background:#f44336; 
        min-height:50px;
        line-height: 18px;        
        overflow: hidden;
        padding:18px 36px; 
        -webkit-box-shadow:2px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
        box-shadow:2px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
        cursor:default;color:#fff;     
        } 
       #myTosterror a{
       color: #FFFFFF;
       }  
#myTostSuccess {
        position: absolute;
        top:0;left:0;
        border-radius:0;
        margin:0;
        overflow: hidden;
        width:100%;
        font-size:14px;
        z-index:1000;
        background:#83B655;
        min-height:50px;
        padding:16px 36px;    
        line-height: 16px;
        -webkit-box-shadow:2px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
        box-shadow:2px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
        cursor:default;color:#fff;
        }
        #myTostSuccess a{
       color: #FFFFFF;
       }  
#myTostnotice {
        position: absolute;
        top:0;left:0;
        border-radius:0;
        margin:0;
        width:100%;
        z-index:1000;
        overflow: hidden;
        font-size:14px;
        background:#033C83;
        min-height:50px;
        padding:16px 36px;
        line-height: 16px;  
        -webkit-box-shadow:2px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
        box-shadow:2px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
        cursor:default;color:#fff;
        }        
       #myTostnotice a{
       color: #FFFFFF;
       }  
.cssanimations.csstransforms #myTostSuccess,#myTosterror,#myTostwarning,#myTostnotice {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
        -webkit-animation: slideDown 10.5s 0.1s 1 ease forwards;
        -moz-transform:    translateY(-100%);
        -moz-animation:    slideDown 10.5s 0.1s 1 ease forwards;
    }
    .cssanimations.csstransforms #close {
      display: none;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes slideDown {
        0%, 100% { -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%); }
        1%, 99% { -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes slideDown {
        0%, 100% { -moz-transform: translateY(-100%); }
        1%, 99% { -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
    }
```

```html
<div id='myTostwarning'>$msg</div>
<div id='myTostSuccess'>$msg</div>
<div id='myTostnotice'>$msg</div>
<div id='myTosterror'>$msg</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
window.onload = function () { document.getElementById("myTostwarning").classList.add('Start-warning'); };
```

and change the class when the page loads.

Comment: What not add it to a if statement on JS or PHP?

Comment: if(password is wrong){ myTostwarning}else if (login){myTostSuccess) etc

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a jQuery CDN in your html file right before the ending `<body>` tag. Here is a CDN...

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

I got that from [here.](https://code.jquery.com/)

Next step would be within your javascript write the following function:

```
 jQuery( document ).ready( function($) {

      //You will now be able to access jquery within this function. Everything in here will wait until the document is loaded before running.

 });
```

Then your javascript script tag would be placed underneath the jquery script tag within the html.

But as @Elroy Fernandes points out you can accomplish this same functionality without the inclusion of jquery.

-Edit -

```
 <div class="notifications">$msg</div>
 <div class="notifications">$msg</div>
 <div class="notifications">$msg</div>
 <div class="notifications">$msg</div>

 jQuery( document ).ready( function($) {

      $(".notifications").each( function(index, element) {
          switch(index) {
              case 0: $(element).attr("id", "myTostwarning");break;
              case 1: $(element).attr("id", "myTostSuccess");break;
              case 2: $(element).attr("id", "myTostnotice");break;
              case 3: $(element).attr("id", "myTosterror");break;
          }
      });
 });
```

Notice that I removed your ids from the html and replaced them with a class "notifications" this is so we can target those specific elements. Then we use jQuery to wait for the document to load and then add an id onto the elements base off of their position in the list. Since the id wont be added until after the page load, the animation wont start until then.

Comment: Do you have any javascript files that would need to wait for the document to load first? I am not sure what the problem is...Are you saying that those ids are not getting the styling from the css? Can you show the errors you are getting?  Can you show any javascript files that you have? There is not really enough information to go on here..

Comment: I would suggest trying to recreate the problem here :jsfiddle.net and then posting the link so that we can see what is happening.

Comment: I don't really know what you are asking. I don't understand the issue. Can you post more code? Can you recreate the problem with http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I updated this with a possible solution if i understand correctly